# Bind to ready and resize at same time using jQuery .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

This works for running the same code on both ready and resize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).resize(function() {

         // Stuff in here happens on ready and resize.

    }).resize(); // Trigger resize handlers.       

});//ready
```

How would you accomplish the same result using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) ?

Comment: `on` is a replacement for `bind`, `live` and `delegate`, but not the shorthand methods. If you ask out of curiosity, fine, but you don't have to change your code to use `.on`.

Comment: @FelixKling I'd like to figure out the fastest way.

Comment: @FelixKling and yea, also just curious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`on` can be used to wire up the resize and ready events just like any other event.

So for your case, you could create a function that has the code you want to happen for `resize` and `ready`, and then pass it to both calls to `on`.

If you want to keep your enclosing scope clean, you could do all this in an immediately executing function:

```
(function() {
    function stuffForResizeAndReady(){
       // Stuff in here happens on ready and resize.
    }

    $(window).on("resize", stuffForResizeAndReady);
    $(document).on("ready", stuffForResizeAndReady);
})();
```

**2012-07-25**: There are 2 differences to be aware of when using `.on()` to attach ready handlers:

- Ready handlers added via `$(fn)` and `$(document).ready(fn)` are "retro-fired" while ones added by `.on()` are not. Using those, if you add a handler after the DOM is already loaded, the fn will be fired immediately. If you add a handler via `.on('ready', fn)` *after* the DOM is loaded, it will *not* be fired by jQuery, but you can manually `.trigger('ready')` it.
- When you use `$(fn)` or `$(document).ready(fn)` to add a ready handler, the fn receives **[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)** as its 1st arg, allowing the familar `jQuery(function($){   })` usage. If you use `$(document).on('ready', fn)`, the 1st arg that the fn receives is an **[event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/event-object/)**. In both cases `this` inside the fn is the `document`. If you were to do something abnormal like `$('#foo').on('ready', fn)` for the purpose of triggering, `this` would be the `#foo` element.

Comment: @ryanve - yeah, you can do some great things with closures in JavaScript

Comment: I choose this answer b/c it's the specific to the question and for its readablity. The answer from @Jasper is also solid and may be faster depending on the situation.

Answer (score 4):

`.ready()`, `.resize()`, and others like `.mouseover()` are all just short-cuts for using the `.bind()` function (or `.on()` in jQuery 1.7+). `.resize(function () {})` maps to `.bind('resize', function () {})`. Here is how your code would look using `.on()` wherever possible:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

    $(window).on('resize', function() {

         // Stuff in here happens on ready and resize.

    }).trigger('resize'); // Trigger resize handlers.       

});//ready
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qMBtP/

Comment: Using `trigger('resize')` makes is faster than `resize()`. This may be the fastest way. http://jsperf.com/bind-to-ready-and-resize-1

Answer (score 0):

Bind it both the load and resize event as below:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
// your code
});
```

Much simpler - hope this helps.