# jQuery get dynamic width of multiple elements on browser resize

Tags: jquery

Title pretty much explains most of my question. I will provide some context.

I've got something like this. (simplified)

```
<ul>
<li><img src="image1.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="image2.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="image3.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

each li is tiled up horizontally. Like so:

```
 [   ][   ][   ][   ]
```

So I already have this script that stretches the image **height** and keeps the aspect ratio.
But now **I need a script which will dynamically get width of all the images (or li) even after the browser has been resized**. 
To my understanding I need something like event bubbling or delegation of some sort. I have no idea how to continue this jQuery journey.

image links to different browser settings I'm talking about

Normal browser height

http://f.cl.ly/items/1O3w3M3l3b3a0z2B0U1w/image1.jpg

Decreased browser height

http://f.cl.ly/items/3y3K38243J063J1U2f1P/image2.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to hook into the `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('li img').each(function(){
        console.log( $(this).width() );
    });
});
```

If you want it to also fire on page load, trigger the `resize` event yourself:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('li img').each(function(){
        console.log( $(this).width() );
    });
})
.resize();
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/39JFQ/

---

If you need the total of all the widths, use this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var totalWidths = 0;

    $('li img').each(function(){
        totalWidths += $(this).width();
    });

    console.log(totalWidths);
})
.resize();
```

Here's the fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/39JFQ/2/

---

You should obviously replace the `li img` selector with something more specific.

Comment: hi, I much appreciate the fiddle! However I want to calculate all the widths together, not just the first one. Maybe I wasnt clear enough. I apologize

Comment: @SebastianGraz - I posted a solution to that.

Comment: Yes the totalWidths did it. I had everything right except the last ".resize();"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an event handler to the window resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    if(width > large){
      $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'largeImage.jpg');
    }else{
      $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'smallImage.jpg');
    }
  });
});
```

Have you considered media queries for this?
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: My mistake. I removed it quickly.

Comment: The variable 'width' will change for each iteration. You need to use it in the loop, push it to an array or something.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need JavaScript at all? Why not just use [responsive CSS](https://github.com/ryanve/css3base/blob/master/responsive-base.css) so that the images adapt:

```
img {
  width: inherit;  /* This makes the next two lines work in IE8. */
  max-width: 100%; /* Add !important if needed. */
  height: auto;    /* Add !important if needed. */
}
```

and use percentage widths on their containers.

To do it in jQuery, you need to attach a handler to the resize event. Use one of the [ways described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976092/bind-to-ready-and-resize-at-same-time-using-jquery-on) or the example using [Response](http://responsejs.com/#hooks) below. I'd use [$.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for storing the width data.

```
Response.action( function () {
    // Code in here runs on ready and on resize:
    $.each($('img'), function() {
        // Get width of element each element:
        var currentWidth = $(this).width(); 
        // Store for access where you need it:
        $.data( this, 'lastWidth', currentWidth ); 
    });//each
});//action
```

See: [responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/](http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/) too.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Response JS looks like a great plugin