# dynamically positioning a absolute element related to another element

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

I have a particular reason to position my logo on a banner and my logo has `postion:absolute`, but when I resize my browser window I have alignment problem, so far I figured out a solution with jQuery which goes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    alert($(document).height());
    var lopos = $('.banner1').children('img').height()/2;
    $('.logo').children('img').css('top', lopos);
});
```

The banner image has `max-width:100%` and I am using jQuery's `height()` to get its height and divide it by 2 so that I can use that to position my logo on top.
I am sucessful so far but the problem is that it happens just on time, and when I rezize my browser I dont see the values change.

Is there a way I can make this code work on window size change?

Comment: Avoid using alerts. console.log("blah") is better in nearly every case: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understand your question correctly, but may I suggest a 'javascript free' solution.

Provided your html looks something like this:

```
<div id='banner'>
    <img src='http://placehold.it/1500x300'/>
     <div id='logo'>logo</div>
</div>
```

You could then position your logo on top of the banner img like this:

```
#banner {
    position: absolute;
}
#banner img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #cff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 50%; 
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

This is assuming that your logo has a fixed size that you know in advance, but i suppose that is a safe assumption...

The 'magic' happens in the two last lines of css. By setting the top to 50% it will make the top of the logo line up with the center of the banner. As the banner has the same size as the image it contains, this means the logo is now lined up with the center of the banner image. By now setting a top margin on the logo, negative half its height, you push it up by 50%, and thus align the center of the logo with the center of the banner image.

I hope this makes sense. Feel free to ask if you want any further explanation, or post some html/css if you want me to make it more concrete for your use case.

I have set up a small fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/pePSZ/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {

    $(window).on('resize', function() {

         // Stuff in here happens on ready and resize.

    }).trigger('resize'); // Trigger resize handlers.       

});//ready
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8976280/1577396)